# Divide Data Into Quartiles

Tags: statistics, dataset, quartile

I have a dataset that contains admissions rates of all providers that we work with. I need to divide that data into quartiles, so that each provider can see where their rate lies in comparison to other providers. The rate ranges from 7% to 89%. can anyone suggest me how to do this? I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question but if somebody can help me with this, I would really appreciate that.

The other concern is that if a provider's numbers is really small eg: 2/4 = 50%, the provider might fall into worse quartile but it doesn't mean that the provider's performance is bad because the numbers are so small. I hope this is making sense. Please let me know if I can clarify it further.

Answer (score 0):

First concern:  For small *n*, do not use quartiles. Whether *n* is small is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to obtain quantiles without doing a complete sort but unless you've got huge amounts of data there is no point in implementing those algorithms if you haven't already got them available. Presuming you have a `sort()` function available, all you need to do is:

1. Given *n* data points.
2. Sort the data points.
3. Find the `n/4`, `n/2` and `3*n/4`th points in the sorted data, which are your quartiles.

As you say, if *n* is less than some number (that you'll have to decide for yourself) you may want to say that the quartile result is "not applicable" or some such.

Comment: Sort data *ascending*, otherwise the interpretation doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I will try out your suggestions. @Jefftopia - If a small n should not be considered into quartiles, that where would a small n go then?

Comment: I think the answer to your question depends on what you want to accomplish. In general, I would advise against using quartiles because they fail to best capture important information about distribution of numbers.  For small `n`, I suppose I would stop at step 2) in @Simon's post.